# How to include JQuery plugins in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-directives

i installed jquery plugin in  angular 2 project [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-bootstrap-scrolling-tabs)

```
npm i jquery-bootstrap-scrolling-tabs
```

and add in `.angular-cli.json`

```
 "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/jquery-bootstrap-scrolling-tabs/dist/jquery.scrolling-tabs.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
         "../node_modules/jquery-bootstrap-scrolling-tabs/dist/jquery.scrolling-tabs.js"
      ],
```

and i declare the veritable  `typings.d.ts`

```
declare var scrollingTabs:any;
```

using in app.component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('.nav-tabs').scrollingTabs({
      scrollToTabEdge: true  
    });
  }
```

error: `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery___default(...)(...).scrollingTabs is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to add the jquery variable

`declare var $ : any`

For more info on how to add jquery use this [**LINK**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) with and without typings

Comment: added still not working. scrollingTabs is not a function

Comment: i would suggest you to use view child and add the template reference to the function instead of the class, tell me if you need a example

Answer (score 1):

Import jquery in your component file.

```
declare let $ : any
```

Comment: any difference from what i added 9 minutes ago