# Angular 2/4 and jquery scripts

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I have added `jQuery` to my `angular 4` project, but I am having trouble using scripts designed to use `jQuery`.

`jQuery` was installed as an npm package then was added via angulars cli using the `typings` command

I would like to access those `jQuery` scripts in my `compontents.ts` files.

The script in question is: [this](https://github.com/wmh/jquery-scrollbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your component you have to declare a global variable for jquery selector like that :

```
import ... 

declare var $: any;

@Component({
 ...
}) 
export class ANY_CLASS implements OnInit{
   ngOnInit() {
     $('#demo').scrollbox();
  }
//use it as you like after that
}
```

and in your template :

```
<div id="demo" class="scroll-text">
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
],
```

and in your component:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: Sorry, but as states in the question, I already have jQuery inplemented via typings, what I am after is how to implement a plugin for jQuery (scrollbox), so I would be able to call `$("#demo").scrollbox()` as per the examples on scrollbars github

Comment: So normally, what I wrote works. $("#demo") will work. I do that in my project.

Comment: I know` $("#demo")` works but I need the last part `.scrollbox()` to work.

Comment: It doesnt work with
 import * as scrollbox from 'jquery.scrollbar' ?

Comment: it doesnt and hence I am asking here, but man I dont get it why people are telling me how to setup jQuery when I literally asked how to add a **jQuery script/plugin**

Comment: Maybe because the main issue about Jquery problem is: how to start it properly. See here how it is used with some ** jQuery script/plugin** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031112/how-to-include-jquery-plugins-in-angular-2

And as you can see, there is no magic here.

Comment: didnt really help