# Trying migrate website based on Jquery to Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular2-template

New to Angular and trying to migrate a website based on jquery to Angular2 and facing issue with java script file included in original project. For example owlCarousel doe not work no matter what I do. I understand there is a angular version of it. But I am trying to make it work without using ng commands in html.
What I observed is that though the script gets called, the owlCarousel object never gets initialized. Below is a code snippet from owlCarousel and console log where angular2 is used and not.
I see the this element in agular2 never refers to div element and I think it is not initializing the object because of that.

I think I am missing something fundamental. Any help or direction on below will greatly help. I am stuck on this for days now.

*Pice of code from owlCarousel:*

```
 $.fn.owlCarousel = function (options) {
    console.log('fn.owlCarousel2');
    console.log( $(this));
    return this.each(function () {
        console.log('inside');
        console.log( $(this));
        if ($(this).data("owl-init") === true) {
             console.log('fn.owlCarousel false');
            return false;
        }
        $(this).data("owl-init", true);
         console.log('fn.owlCarousel object creation');
        var carousel = Object.create(Carousel);
        carousel.init(options, this);
        $.data(this, "owlCarousel", carousel);
    });
};
```

*Log from Angular2:*

> OWL Carousel owl.carousel.js:1451 fn.owlCarousel2
>      owl.carousel.js:1452 jQuery.fn.init [selector: "#owl-main-demo",
>      context: document] owl.carousel.js:1451 fn.owlCarousel2
>      owl.carousel.js:1452 jQuery.fn.init [selector: "#owl-second-demo",
>      context: document] owl.carousel.js:1451 fn.owlCarousel2
>      owl.carousel.js:1452 jQuery.fn.init [selector: "#owl-third-demo",
>      context: document] theme.js:266 Theme.js owl options
>      owl.carousel.js:1451 fn.owlCarousel2 owl.carousel.js:1452
>      jQuery.fn.init [selector: "#owl-product-slide", context: document]
>      owl.carousel.js:1451 fn.owlCarousel2 owl.carousel.js:1452
>      jQuery.fn.init [selector: "#owl-text-slide", context: document]
>      owl.carousel.js:1451 fn.owlCarousel2 owl.carousel.js:1452
>      jQuery.fn.init [selector: "#owl-featured-slide", context: document]
>      owl.carousel.js:1451 fn.owlCarousel2 owl.carousel.js:1452
>      jQuery.fn.init [selector: "#owl-blog-slide", context: document]

*Log where Angular is not used:*

> OWL Carousel     owl.carousel.js:1449 fn.owlCarousel
>      owl.carousel.js:1450 jQuery.fn.init [selector: "#owl-main-demo",
>      context: document] owl.carousel.js:1449 fn.owlCarousel
>      owl.carousel.js:1450 jQuery.fn.init [selector: "#owl-second-demo",
>      context: document] owl.carousel.js:1449 fn.owlCarousel
>      owl.carousel.js:1450 jQuery.fn.init [selector: "#owl-third-demo",
>      context: document] theme.js:266 Theme.js owl options
>      owl.carousel.js:1449 fn.owlCarousel owl.carousel.js:1450
>      jQuery.fn.init [**div#owl-product-slide.owl-carousel**.product-slide,
>      selector: "#owl-product-slide", context: document]
>      owl.carousel.js:1452 inside owl.carousel.js:1453 jQuery.fn.init
>      [div#owl-product-slide.owl-carousel.product-slide, context:
>      div#owl-product-slide.owl-carousel.product-slide]
>      owl.carousel.js:1459 fn.owlCarousel object creation
>      owl.carousel.js:29 OWL Carousel in init owl.carousel.js:40 OWL
>      Carousel loadcontent owl.carousel.js:72 OWL Carousel login
>      owl.carousel.js:103 OWL Carousel onstart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include JQuery plugins in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031112/how-to-include-jquery-plugins-in-angular-2)

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031112/how-to-include-jquery-plugins-in-angular-2 about how to use jQuery's plugins in an ng2+ app.